# Euler's Phi Function and Congruences

Tags: number-theory

Given Euler's Phi function and two sets of two primes, can there be a congruence such that:

$n_{1}=\varphi(p_{1}-1)(q_{1}-1)$

$n_{1}=\varphi(p_{2}-1)(q_{2}-1)$

I apologize if this has a trivial answer.

Comment: Do you mean $\phi((p_1-1)(q_1-1))$ or $(\phi(p_1-1))\cdot (q_1-1)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , if you mean $\ \phi((p_1-1)\cdot (q_1-1))\ $ , you can choose $$p_1=5,q_1=13,p_2=7,q_2=11$$  you get $16$ in both cases.

If you mean $\ (\phi(p_1-1))\cdot (q_1-1)\ $ , you can choose $$p_1=3,q_1=13,p_2=5,q_2=7$$  you get $12$ in both cases.

Comment: Thank you for your response.